# Как избавится от ошибки с переменными char

Tags: java, c++

Смысл в программе в том что она должна вывести на консоль 4 значения: Potatos, Tomatos, Apple, Orange. Но вместо этого выводит предупреждение [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]. В итоге выводит на экран знаки вопроса. Также еще вопрос на счет того что прописывать в скобках: `Storage a = Storage();` В Java я писал: `GoodIntrf a=new Fruit();`

GoodIntrf.h

```
class GoodIntrf {
public:
    virtual char GetName (int id) = 0; 
};
```

Fruit.h

```
#include "GoodIntrf.h"
class Fruit : public GoodIntrf
{
public:
    char* getName(int id) {
        if (id == 1) return "Apple";
        if (id == 2) return "Orange";
        else return "Unknown type";
    }
};
```

Vegetable.h

```
#include "GoodIntrf.h"
class Vegetable : public GoodIntrf
{
public:
    char* getName(int id) {
        if (id == 1) return "Potato";
        if (id == 2) return "Tomato";
        else return "Unknown type";
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Fruit.h"
#include "Vegetable.h"
#include "GoodIntrf.h"
class Storage : public GoodIntrf
{
public:
    char GetName(int id) {
        return id;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Storage a = Storage();
    std::cout << a.GetName(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.GetName(2) << std::endl;
    Storage a = Storage();
    std::cout << a.GetName(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.GetName(2) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Прекратите возвращать `char *` из функций, возвращающий указатели на строковые литералы. В С++ строковые литерал имеет тип `const char [N]` и, соответственно, приводится к указателю `const char *`, а не `char *`. Исправляйте все типы возврата на `const char *`.

Отдельно неясно, почему эти функции вообще являются членами каких-то классов. Они же со своим классом вообще никак не общаются. Что за странные функции с именами, отличающимися только капитализацией: `GetName` и `getName`. В чем замысел? Почему вдруг `Storage::GetName` возвращает `char`? Причем здесь вообще классы `Vegetable` и `Fruit`, если в программе они никак не используются?

Что касается того "что прописывать в скобках" - об этом пока рано говорить, ибо совершенно не ясно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.